# Need some help with a function of the form $ x*f(x)$

Tags: functions

https://www.dropbox.com/s/wftcle723fa51xg/reciprocal.jpg

I can do the first part so don't waste your time on that.
A good explanation for b would be appreciated.

Comment: after x=2 your function seems to behave as y=x, so it would become $x^2$ after x=2.  From $x=0 to 2$ it looks like $(y+1)=(x-1)^2$.For x<0 it looks like an ellipse. so u could multiply by x and draw the new functions. This is pure GuessWork BTW.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
The function has two roots 0,and 2

and denominator has not root because it has no vertical asymptote

so 1/f(x) has 2 vertical asymptote at x=0,2

and xf(x) has diagonal asymptote with slope of 2x

Comment: I did started with supposed function but it look like that

Comment: Don't forget the horizontal asymptotes of $\frac1{f(x)}$: One at $y=\frac12$ as $x\to-\infty$ and $y=0$ as $x\to+\infty$.